# Remove trailing dot from number and remove round brackets around numbers using sed

Tags: unix, sed

I have the following data

```
X.|X.X|abcdefesd|(XXXX)|XXXXXXXXX
```

and I'm using sed to format it as

```
X|X.X|abcdefesd|XXXX|XXXXXXXXX
```

X = numbers

I am using the command  `sed "s/\([0-9]+\)/\1/g"` for the 1st column ( The numbers can be from 1 digit to 3 digit here)

and `sed 's/[^(]*(\([^)]*\)).*/\1/g'`  for the 4th column ( the number will always be 4 digits)

I am currently new to unix

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Both the commands im using are not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
sed -e 's/\([0-9]\+\)\.\([^0-9]\)/\1\2/g' -e 's/(\([0-9]\+\))/\1/g'
```

`-e` is used to chain multiple sed sommands. The first one captures and sequence of digits followed by a dot and then followed by a non-digit, and replaces it without the dot. The second one just replaces any sequence of digits inside brackets with the same sequence without brackets.

```
echo "2.|3.5|abcdefesd|(3455)|2412412414" | sed -e 's/\([0-9]\+\)\.\([^0-9]\)/\1\2/g' -e 's/(\([0-9]\+\))/\1/g'
2|3.5|abcdefesd|3455|2412412414
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be simpler using `awk`.  Try:

```
awk -F'|' -vOFS='|' '{$1=sprintf("%d",$1);gsub("[^0-9]","",$4)}1' inputfile
```

Example:

```
$ awk -F'|' -vOFS='|' '{$1=sprintf("%d",$1);gsub("[^0-9]","",$4)}1' <<< "2.|3.5|abcdefesd|(3455)|2412412414"
2|3.5|abcdefesd|3455|2412412414
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just remove the parentheses?

```
awk '{gsub(/[()]/,x)}1' <<< "2.|3.5|abcdefesd|(3455)|2412412414"
2.|3.5|abcdefesd|3455|2412412414
```